# Can Gibbs Sampling be used to generate synthetic data from the posterior distribution?

Tags: bayesian, gibbs

I am working with a few datasets. I would like to expand some of them somehow by creating synthetic data. Is it possible to use a Gibbs Sampler to, by sampling a given distribution of the original data, create synthetic data points?

Comment: What do you mean `synthetic data points`? You can use a Gibbs Sampler to sample an infinite number of observations from the distribution.

Comment: Say I have a dataset with different observations (Age, Country, Blood Level, etc.). Can the observations extracted from the distribution be used to synthetically augment this dataset? (from a feasability and reasonability point of view)

Comment: But what do you mean by "augment"? In what way?

Comment: Well if I have 100 samples, augment it to have 200 samples for example

Comment: You are likely looking for the Posterior Predictive Distribution(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution) - which is the distribution of potential new / unobserved data given the observed data. Given samples (for instance, using Gibbs sampling) from the posterior distribution of the parameters, you can use your model to translate these into samples from the data given the parameters.